# A best way to retrieve object from array

Tags: javascript

I have to 'filter' the ids of objects who's in array,
I find this method but I think is not the best :

```
const idToCompare = 456

MyArray = [{name: 'One, brand: [{id: 456, name:'Hello'},{id: 857, name:'Hi'},{id: 456, name:'Goodbye'},{id: 123, name:'See you'}]} ]
```

so now I do:

```
let filtered = myArray.map(a => a.brand.filter(b => b.id === idToCompare))

Console.log(filtered ) // [[{id: 456, name:'Hello'},{id: 456, name:'Goodbye'}]]
```

I need to flat() it to have

```
filtered.flat()
Console.log(filtered ) // [{id: 456, name:'Hello'},{id: 456, name:'Goodbye'}]
```

How can I do in best way or a simple way ?

Comment: Use the array method `flat`? Or maybe even `flatMap`?

Comment: Your example is confusing because it's impossible to tell if your `MyArray` will only ever have one item, or if it might have multiple

Comment: I use it , but is a best way to make this in simple way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) instad of [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const
    array = [{ name: 'One', brand: [{ id: 456, name: 'Hello' }, { id: 857, name: 'Hi' }, { id: 456, name:'Goodbye'}, { id: 123, name: 'See you' }] }],
    idToCompare = 456,
    filtered = array.flatMap(({ brand }) => brand.filter(({ id }) => id === idToCompare));

console.log(filtered)
```